# Hide toolbar of PDF opened in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, tcpdf

I want to hide the toolbar of a pdf which is opened in a browser(firefox).

I tried the following code,but it is not working:

```
<embed src="test.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="425" height="425">
```

Can i show only zoom in/out feature?
Please let me know if any other solution is there.

Thanks .

Comment: any solution on this?

Comment: Doesn't look like there is any solution to this. If this functionality is really needed check out pdf.js